# iPad - AG.Calendar doesn't go full width

Tags: ipad, titanium, titanium-modules

Version used: 1.2.3
I added the modules to my tiapp.xml:
        ag.calendar

here's a link to what it looks like: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/101794062/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Oct%2031%2C%202012%2010.35.51%20PM.png

I made sure that there are no actual static width's set. The weird thing is that the calendar is starting to go the full width, but not quite. The header part and the footer part of the calendar just aren't going the full width.

Link to the module I used: https://github.com/Appgutta/AGCalendar

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with the module itself

Comment: can you post the code where you instantiate the calendar?

Comment: I could, looks like someone would have to fix it within the module itself (which I'm hoping the developer finishes, because I'm new to objective c). He confirmed it in a comment to another question asked on Titaniums Q&A section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the KalViewController.m replace line 196 with the following:

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, windowsRect.size.width, windowsRect.size.height);
    //CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, MIN(popoverRect.size.width, windowsRect.size.width),         MIN(popoverRect.size.height, windowsRect.size.height));
```